# Finding file in windows path

Tags: python

I'm trying to get someone else's Python script to run on my computer and part of the script finds a file in the USERPROFILE. Here is that code:

```
    for w in os.walk(os.getenv('USERPROFILE')):
        if 'FilenName' in w[1]: 
            path = str(w[0]) + r'\FilenName\UsrData\Directory\Data'
```

However, in the above code, the program tries to search in the following directory:

> C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\

When, in fact, the program should be looking in

> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\

If I replace the problem code with the following, it works, but I need it to run for all USERPROFILEs, not just mine:

```
path = r'C:\Users\Bill\AppData\Local\FilenName\UsrData\Directory\Data'
```

What is the solution to this?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like an OS mismatch. What operating system was the code designed for and what OS are you running on?

Comment: Also,  for me (and according to docs), `%USERPROFILE%` resolves to `C:\Users\MyUsername`

Comment: The problem is that the original code should not be using environment variables to locate the user profile. It should be using the winapi. More importantly though, are you 100% sure that it is always stored in the local profile rather than the roaming profile? What evidence do you have that this is always the case, and not just the case on one specific machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not on a windows machine, so this is a bit tricky, but could you find all user profiles using the env var ALLUSERSPROFILE?

Another option may be to replace "Roaming" with "Local" in the string. It's a bit hacky, but can be done:

```
for w in os.walk(os.getenv('USERPROFILE')):
    if 'FilenName' in w[1]: 
        path = (str(w[0]) + r'\FilenName\UsrData\Directory\Data').replace('Roaming', 'Local')
```

Comment: A "better" hack would probably be to use the `%USERNAME%` env variable and insert that into the `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\ ` string (in case this gets ported to yet another system)

Comment: I think that one may be the best option, unless OP is in need of all usernames at once. A bit difficult to tell from the phrasing.